# Weekly booking calendar - change date error

Tags: jquery, date, calendar

I have a problem with date.js

There is my resource: 
http://fiddle.jshell.net/95GVF/

why can change the date only once?

Thanks for help.

Comment: A better question would show code here and also provide a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this:

When you first build the HTML, you then put click listeners on .prev and .next.

Then when the click occurs, you rebuild the HTML and replace the old but do not put new click listeners on the new .prev and .next elements.

You have a few solutions:

1) Attach the click listeners everytime you rebuld the HTML.

2) Move the .prev and .next "buttons" outside the generated HTML and put them in the base page. Then they are not regenerated every time.

3) Add a `on` listener to the div surrounding the generated code. When the click event bubbles up to the div, it will check whether the original element is .prev or .next and do the handler code if it is. (You should look up the jQuery documentation on `.on()` for current jQuery versions or `.live` for older versions.)